# C# Format String as Date

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

I have a DetailsView with a TextBox bound to a DateTime column. The value of the column is presented in the format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss". I need it to be displayed in the format "yyyy/mm/dd". I had though that the best way may be to format the string in the DataBound event. Problem is, I can't seem to find a way to format the string as a date. The String.Format won't do it. If I had the string as a DateTime then I could use the DateTime.Format method. I could create a datetime variable by parsing the various elements of the string but I can't help but think there must be an easier way?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public static string GetDateString(string date)
{
    DateTime theDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out theDate))
    {
        // the string was successfully parsed into theDate
        return theDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
    }
    else
    {
        // the parsing failed, return some sensible default value
        return "Couldn't read the date";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string testDate = "19/08/2010 06:19:30";
DateTime asDate = DateTime.ParseExact(testDate,
   "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(asDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a DateTime then then use string.format to format it how you want.

```
    DateTime MyDateTime = Convertto.Date"01/12/2004 00:35:23",
   "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string.Format("The Date is:{0}", "yyyy/MM/dd",MyDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

DataFormatString="{0:d}". You can give this property to your field. Write this in ASP page

Comment: I wasn't aware of the DataFormatString property - thank you.

However, it seems DateFormatSting can only be used with a BoundColumn. My field is a TemplateField so that I can add a Validator to ensure that during Edit / Insert, the correct format it used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TextBox You may consider to use MaskedTextBox, then only thing that You do is to set the mask (format).

[Read More about MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)